# Banned from making edits?

Tags: support, editing

On  of my preferred activities on this stackexchange is to edit answers and questions where necessary.

However, as of late, it seem I am unable to do so as easily as previously.

I've started using the mobile app to answer questions and at first I thought it was that. It would display a red banner say something like 'This user is banned from suggesting edits'. But I've just copied my edit changes into a version of stackexchange in my browser for [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11932/wife-asking-for-mehar-after-forgiving-it) question. Upon clicking submit however I don't see the normal 'your changes will be visible when the have been reviewed' message.

Has something happened to my account, or is it my use of mobile that's triggered it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be a limitation of the app, not any problem with your account (I just checked: you are not currently, and as far as I can tell have never been, banned from suggesting edits for any reason).

Apparently, the Stack Exchange API supports making edits, [but does not support *suggesting* edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208471/132874).  As such, attempting to edit on any site where you don't have full edit privileges (e.g. 1000 rep on beta sites) will just fail if you use the mobile app, but will succeed (as a suggested edit) if you browse to the site.

Comment: Thanks. Time to start earning more reputation.